# cross join in query itself to match to see if it is not a last record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a record to match if its sortorder is not the last one in the complete recordset within a query itself

tried this query it gives me the min and count but what i am trying to get

```
WITH s AS (
  SELECT MyGroup, Count(MyGroup) AS [Count], 
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Count(MyGroup)) AS [rasc],
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Count(MyGroup) DESC) AS [rdesc]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY (MyGroup)
)
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN [rasc] = 1 THEN 'Min'
    ELSE 'Max' 
  END AS 'Agg',
  [MyGroup], 
  [Count]
FROM s
WHERE [rasc] = 1 OR [rdesc] = 1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The query doesn't make sense with respect to the question.

Comment: If you are trying to get the MIN/MAX per MyGroup then the query above will not work. There is no partition by group so you will end up with only 1 record for where rasc=1 for the entire result set. Perhaps you are missing a  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MyGroup ORDER BY Count(MyGroup))